# I am trying to work with angular(tailwind) and docker but whenever I try to access localhost:4200 I always get err_empty_response

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, tailwind-css

below is the dockerfile docker-compose and package.json What I am mostly concerned about is the path and I have tryed to add CMD ["npm","start",--host 0.0.0.0] and didn't work what could be wrong ?

here is the dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:14
ENV PATH=$PATH:app/node_modules/.bin
#app/
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

# add app
#COPY . .

# start app
EXPOSE 4200


CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And the docker compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    container_name: template
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

Part of the package.json file*

```
  "name": "notus-angular",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Notus Angular - Free Tailwind CSS UI Kit and Admin by Creative Tim.",
  "repository": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/notus-angular",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 1000 ",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:tailwind": "tailwind build src/assets/styles/index.css -o src/assets/styles/tailwind.css",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm run build:tailwind && npm start"
  },
```

I am suspecting that smthg is wrong with the path or the node_modules emplacement

Comment: What's the actual problem you're running into?  The `volumes:` block you have overwrites the entire useful contents of the image, including its `node_modules` directory, and this can lead to problems; does deleting the `volumes:` block make any difference?  The `CMD` you propose in text isn't syntactically valid, does it work if you make sure it's a correctly-quoted JSON array?

Comment: no it does not yes u r right

Comment: I actually must have a volume what is wrong with it can you please explain

Comment: You have two copies of your application.  One is built into the image, but you never use that, because the volume mount overrides it.  If you want to run the code on your host without using Docker's image system, it will be much easier to just use Node without bothering with Docker.

Comment: how to correct the override I have tried to comment the volumes I get npm error

Comment: in this project I must use docker

Comment: @DavidMaze when removing the volumes I get this error The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

Comment: ...did you comment out the `COPY` line that includes the application in the image?  Uncomment that.

Comment: do you mean this line # add app
#COPY . .?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've recently created an angular development
environment. My docker File:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
CMD ["ng","serve","--host","0.0.0.0"]
```

And my compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  angular_devel:
    image: angular:1.0.0
    container_name: angular_devel
    hostname: angular_devel
    ports: 
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes: 
      - "./angular_devel/node_modules:/app/node_modules"
      - "./angular_devel:/app"
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - main
      - database

networks: 
  main:
    driver: bridge
  database:
    driver: bridge
```

On my compose file I've mapped two volumes. But later on I realized that the first line was redundant. Some of my docker.ignore / git ignore exclude the node_modules somehow.... hope it helps.